# Number of subgroups and normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

I am struggling to understand how to calculate the nunmber of subgroups with permutations, for example:

- How many normal subgroups does S3 have?
- How many subgroups of order 4 has group S4?
- And does group S5 have a subgroup of order 5 or 6?

Is the only way to approach this to try all the possiblities? And how does the calculation differ for normal subgroups?

Comment: The third part is easy: you can construct elements of $S_5$ that have orders 5 and 6.

Comment: In general, finding the number of subgroups (normal or otherwise) is really hard (but fortunately these are small examples, where one can easily just try by hand).